# Pyomo TypeError: unhashable type: 'EqualityExpression'

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I am building an energy planning model in Pyomo and I am running into problems building some power grid constraints.

```
    def grid2grid_rule(m, ts):
        return m.power['grid','grid', ts] == 0
    m.const_grid2grid = Constraint(ts_i, grid2grid_rule)

    def import_rule(m, ts):
        return m.gridImport[ts] == sum(m.power['grid',derIn,ts] for derIn in elIn)

    m.const_import = Constraint(ts_i, rule = import_rule)

    def export_rule(m, ts):
        return m.gridExport[ts] == sum(m.power[derOut,'grid',ts] for derOut in elOut)

    m.const_export = Constraint(ts_i, export_rule)
```

Definition of Power:

```
m.power = Var(elOut, elIn, ts_i, within = NonNegativeReals)
```

Explaining the code:
m.power is a decision variable with 3 indices: The electricity source (elOut), the electricity 'usage' (elIn) and the current timestep index ts_i. elOut and elIn are numpy arrays with strings and ts_i a numpy array with integers from 0 to how many timesteps there are.

The first constraint just says that at any timestep there the electricity cannot flow from the grid to the grid. The import constraint says that the grid imports at each timestep are the sum over all power flows from the grid to electricity takers. The export constraint says that the grid exports at each timestep are a sum of all powerflows from electricity 'givers' to the grid.

Now, my problem is, when I comment the grid2grid and the export constraint, it works and a set of constraints is built as expected. However, for example when I uncomment the export rule, which is almost identical to the import rule, I get this error:

```
m = build_model('Input_Questionaire.xlsx', 'DER_excel', yeardivision = "repr_day")
ERROR: Constructing component 'const_export_index_1' from data=None failed:
    TypeError: Problem inserting gridExport[1]  ==  power[pv_ground,grid,1] +
    power[wind_s,grid,1] + power[battery,grid,1] + power[grid,grid,1] into set
    const_export_index_1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Axel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\sets.py", line 824, in add
    if tmp in self:

  File "C:\Users\Axel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\sets.py", line 998, in __contains__
    return self._set_contains(element)

  File "C:\Users\Axel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\sets.py", line 1302, in _set_contains
    return element in self.value

TypeError: unhashable type: 'EqualityExpression'
```

Accompanied with this error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  ...
  ...

  File "C:\Users\Axel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\sets.py", line 833, in add
    raise TypeError("Problem inserting "+str(tmp)+" into set "+self.name)

TypeError: Problem inserting gridExport[1]  ==  power[pv_ground,grid,1] + power[wind_s,grid,1] + power[battery,grid,1] + power[grid,grid,1] into set const_export_index_1
```

I do not know how to fix it, especially since there is basically no difference in the two Constraints...
Thanks heaps for your help!

Axel

Comment: It is likely that you are supplying a bad index to `power[i,j,k]`.  Can you edit your code and show where `power` is defined?  I'm guessing `power[grid, grid, i] is a problem, but not sure.  Also, if you are going to index Pyomo variables with numpy arrays, I would just make pyomo sets from them.  It really helps in troubleshooting to prevent problems like this.

Comment: Thanks @JeffH! I added the definition of power. In the actual code it is defined before the constraints of course. The indices are all numpy arrays. elOut can eg. contain 'pv', 'battery', 'grid' or other sources of electricity and elIn can for example contain 'load', 'battery' or 'grid'. ts_i is just an integer starting with 0.
I thought about using Pyomo Sets and Parameters instead. I will try to change this.
I am pretty certain it cannot be the power[grid,grid,i] issue as this exists with the import constraint as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh... just saw it.  It's an easy one.  :)

you omitted "rule=" portion of the constraint construction, so it is passing in the function as a set or something weird...

Anyhow.  Change:

```
 m.const_export = Constraint(ts_i, export_rule)
```

to:

```
 m.const_export = Constraint(ts_i, rule=export_rule)
```

same for your `grid2grid`

Comment: Thanks! I have no clue how I could have overseen this xD.
Sorry I cannot upvote your answer as my reputation is too low but it works now :)

Comment: Cool.  Even if you can't upvote, you can still "accept" it.  Even though it was just a typo fix.  :)

Comment: Ah perfect I did not see the little tick =)
Accepted! And you reckon I should make all the parameters and numpy arrays to Pyomo parameters and sets?

Comment: It doesn't hurt.  It's only a 1-liner.  and it makes it much easier to T/S the model when you print it off with m.pprint() to see all the sets and values.  All you need to do is:  `m.el_out = Set(initialize=elOut).  (I don't always follow my own advice though!)

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks!